# Box2d libgdx very slow on device

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx, frame-rate

its supposed that, a time step is necesary to run a game at the correct speed,  a fast hardware will adjust the speed to 30 or 60 fps, otherwise, the game will run so fast as the hardware can handle it. Now, my game runs as expected on the pc, but, when is launched on the device(galaxy ace), the body moves very slow, even has a maximum speed wich can not exceed, whatever be amount in Body.AppliLinearImpulse or AppliForce, also, i've changed the setLinearVelocity to a very high number, and always is the same speed.
could be a bug on libgdx box2d? or a bug with my galaxy ace android 2.3

Comment: This may has several reasons, check your fps by printing it. If fps was low the problem is in your codes or resources. else if fps was good the problem is in your "world" how you call world.step(...) ?
I've tested Galaxy ace with my own game that also uses libgdx and I hadn't any problem.

Comment: i really dont know what is the problem. i've tried with all values on the "world" from 1/60 to an integer, and higher, the fps are normal, 30 or 60, as i want, the problem keeps being the "World", also, i downloaded examples from the net, and executed on the device, and is the same thing :/ and in the pc runs very well, using the specified value on .AppliForce. anyway, y found what i wanted with an MuseJoint, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably simulating Box2D bodies while passing in the dimensions equal to pixel values. Box2D runs in meters, however, so creating bodies 300 meters in size really puts a low ceiling on your entire simulation.

Recommended approach is to use arbitrary ratio (1m == 64px) and scale down your Box2D system - initialize and manipulate bodies using meter values converted from px.

This will allow for a wider variety of motion and a higher ceiling on velocity. Had the same issue as you and took me a bit of time to figure it out.